# Neo4J and Talend BD inserting a relationship - node doesn't exist

Tags: database, neo4j, batch-processing, etl, talend

I use Talend Open Studio Big Data to migrate my MySQL DB to Neo4j, i successfully migrated about 5 tables and 4 relations but I got stuck on a very weird problem. When inserting a relationship I get:

```
Exception in component tNeo4jOutputRelationship_1
java.lang.RuntimeException: End node looked up by index with _id as key and Skill.4 as value doesn't exist
```

but:

- the node clearly exists and gets picked up by an appropriate cypher query (using the _id index of course)
- the node is defined as starting node, not end node and I'm dead sure everything is set up correctly because outputing a delimited file shows proper structure

Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few furious hours I found the solution - the error message specifies a wrong node - it was actualy the other node (the other end of the relationship) that was causing the problem.

Also beware of setting the connection on every neo4j operation in embedded mode - if you don't the job will execute fine, not give you any error but not do anything...

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest, as this is a specific question, is to go on the editor's forum to ask the question. Community members and the team will be able to help out on your question and give you advice. They might even ask you to bugtrack the question!

Here a link to the Big Data product forum:
http://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewforum.php?id=35

Best,
TD.